# Wanderlust or other imap mail reader on native windows emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, wanderlust

I'm trying to get my windows based emacs to handle mails. Is there any emacs based mail reader that would run on windows? By running, I mean fetch from imap, show and reply to mails without external applications.

I've heard many good things about [Wanderlust](http://www.gohome.org/wl/) but the webpage suggests it is not supported.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wanderlust is a great mail reader and it's community is still quite alive. As for Windows related questions, try to [search](http://lists.airs.net/wl-en/archive/) or ask in wl-en mailing list. People are very friendly and helpful there. Also, EmacsWiki [page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WanderLust) could be useful too.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Gnus does the trick.  Read about it on the [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail).

Comment: Thanks, I will check this. However I don't see instructions for windows and for Linux I see that there are some external dependencies "You will need starttls, which is used to set up the SSL encrypted connection to the GMail server. This is contained in the “gnutls-bin” package on earlier versions of debian and ubuntu. ". I'd like to avoid cygwin if possible. But if not, I could live with that. Either way I will check this in the afternoon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gnus does not run on windows, there are [TLS issues](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.gnus.user/14869) that I have reported.